# gdb shows wrong instruction

Tags: ida, android, gdb

I'm debugging `android jni` with `gdb`. There's a `jni` function `A()`, I need to set `breakpoint` there and step through. I calculated the address with `module_base+offset`, which is `0x99B62C7A`, then I tried to verify if it's the right address, with `gdb` command:

```
display /5i 0x99B62C7A
```

It prints some unexpected instructions, which is different from `IDA`:
[image]

And if I put a `breakpoint` there and click on the UI to trigger the `breakpoint`, the process crashes with `SIGSEGV`.

So why `gdb` displays different instructions? Is the crash has something to do with the bad instruction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your instructions shown by Ida are Thumb-mode instructions. The easiest way to verify this is by checking the addresses - each instruction has 2 bytes. Gdb doesn't know this however, and assumes 4 byte arm instructions. When an object has a symbol table, gdb can detect the instruction mode from that, but will fallback to a default mode when it can't. You can change this fallback mode; `set arm fallback-mode thumb` should do the trick.

This explains the SIGSEGV as well as breakpoints use different opcodes in arm and thumb mode.